# Swift - generics in closure

Tags: generics, swift, closures

I'm coming from the .NET world, so I'm a little confused about how generics are implemented in Swift.  I am trying to do the following:

```
func request<T: Model>(resultHandler: (model: T?) -> ()) {
        var model: T? = nil

        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: self.url)!) {
            data, response, error in
                if let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                    model = T(json: json)

                    resultHandler(model: model)
                }
            }.resume()
    }
```

And consume it as follows:

```
var store: HttpStore = HttpStore(url: ...)

store.request {
            model in
                println("Task name: \(model.name!)")
        }
```

I get the following error:

> 'T?' does not have a member named 'name'

And I get why.  I'm not resolving T to a particular type anywhere in my calling code.  In .NET I would do something like store.request< Task >()...  But I can't do that in Swift.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A closure expression generally has the form

```
{ (param_1 : type_1, ..., param_n : type_n ) -> return_type in
    statements
}
```

When the closure type is known or can be inferred from the context then you can omit the parameter types, the return type (and also the parentheses around the parameters):

```
{ param_1, ..., param_n in
    statements
}
```

But in your code

```
store.request {
    model in
    // ...
}
```

the type of the closure cannot be inferred from the context, and you have to write
it explicitly as

```
store.request {
    (model : Task?) -> () in
    // ...
}
```

or (the return type `()` aka `Void` can be omitted):

```
store.request {
    (model : Task?) in
    // ...
}
```

---

Note that inside the block, `model` is an *optional*. As [Antonio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148357/antonio) already said in a now deleted answer,
you will have to unwrap the optional, so

```
println("Task name: \(model.name!)")
```

should probably be

```
println("Task name: \(model!.name)")
```

If `model` might be `nil` then you can use optional binding to test it:

```
if let theModel = model {
    println("Task name: \(theModel.name)")
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.  I tried to specify the type in the 'in' statement, but forgot to use parentheses.